# quesiton about taylor series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Calculate $f'(0)$, $f''(0)$ and $f'''(0)$ where
$$f(x)=(\sin x)·(\cos x)^{1808} ·(\exp x^{601})·(1+3x^3−5x^4 +2754x^{232})$$

I know we should solve it use the Taylor series for sins, cosx, and expo, but I have no idea of how to use it? Can anybody give some hint? Thank you.

Comment: I edited, but am not sure if that is supposed to be $\exp(x^{601})$ or $(\exp x)^{601}$ ...

Comment: It is exp(x^601). You do it right!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\cos x = 1-\frac12x^2+O(x^3) $$
hence $$(\cos x)^n=1-\frac n2x^2+O(x^3) $$
(because in multiplying out, everything but the simplest cases hides away in the big-O).
Also note that
$$ \exp x = 1+x+O(x^2)$$
so that for $n\ge 3$
$$ \exp(x^n)=1+x^n+O(x^{2n})=1+O(x^3)$$
The final polynomial factor is also $1+O(x^3)$. Therefore
$$(\cos x)^{1808}(\exp x^{601})(1+3x^3-5x^4+2754x^{232})=1-904x^2+O(x^3) $$
As $$\sin x = x-\frac16x^3+O(x^4) $$
the complete expression is
$$f(x)=x-904\tfrac16\,x^3 +O(x^4).$$
You can read off the derivatives by comparing with 
$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac12f''(0)x^2+\frac16f'''(0)x^3+O(x^4). $$

Comment: Don't you want $\cos x = 1-x^2/2 +O(x^4)$? (Any $O(x^3)$ term could contribute to $f'''(0).$)

Comment: @zhw. It would, if $\sin x$ had a constant term

Comment: Oh, right. Never mind and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is differentiable (at least) $4$ times at $0$, it has the Maclaurin series
$$f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x+\frac{1}{2}f''(0)x^2+\frac{1}{3!}f'''(0)x^3 + \mathcal{O}(x^4), \ \mathrm{as} \ x \to 0$$

To find $f'(0)$ in your expression, you add all 1st order terms and read off the coefficient. To find $f''(0)$, you add all 2nd order terms and read off the coefficient times $2$. To find $f'''(0)$, you add all 3rd order terms and read off the coefficient times $3!$

Thus expand $\sin x$, $\cos x$ and $\exp x$ to the 3rd order, multiply everything together, collect the terms, and follow the recipe above. Of course, you can neglect any term of higher order than $2$ in the polynomial in the 4th factor.

Comment: I think you need $o(x^3)$ there, not $O(x^4).$

Comment: @zhw. What I mean is that $|\mathcal{O}(x^4)| \leq M |x^4|$, for some constant $M$, when $x$ is small. Isn't this correct?

Comment: I know what you meant, but it's not correct. Try $f(x) = |x|^{7/2}$ for example.

Comment: @zhw.Well, that's certainly not three times differentiable at the origin, distributional derivatives aside.

Comment: Let $f(x)=|x|^{7/2}.$ Then $f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=f'''(0)=0.$

Comment: @zhw. I agree that $f(0)=f'(0) = 0$, but not that $f''(0) = f'''(0)=0$. Feel free to show me. What I have stated is simply Taylor's theorem with the remainder on Peano form (unless I'm completely mistaken).

Comment: It's just a calculation. Here's an easier one: Let $f(x) = |x|^{3/2}.$ Then $f(0)=f'(0)=0.$ But $f$ is not $O(x^2).$

Comment: @zhw. Okay, yes for that function you have $f(0)=f'(0)$. But still $f$ is $\mathcal{O}(x^2)$ because $|x|^{3/2}$ goes to zero faster than does $|x|^2$. I don't get what you think the problem is?

Comment: No, $x^2\to 0$ faster than $|x|^{3/2}.$

Comment: @zhw. Sorry, you're right of course in that $x^2$ goes to zero faster than $|x|^{3/2}$. I realize now what the problem is. In my answer I must require $f$ to be at least four times differentiable. In our example, I must require $f(x) = |x|^{3/2}$ to be twice differentiable at the origin in order to claim that $f$ is $\mathcal{O}(x^2)$. Obviously, the function doesn't meet this criterion.